# String output on timed event

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am starting to develop an android app. I am looking to start the app and have a message grabbed from an SQLite DB and post it on the screen and then periodically grab a new query and exchange the old message for a new one, about every 30 seconds.

Essentially it is posting quotes that are being refreshed for new ones after giving the user some time to read them.

I am wondering what would be the correct way about going about this?

Should I use the `Handler` class? Or `Timer`? Or is there a better way of getting a timed event?

And after I have the timed event, how would I update the text on the app? I am trying to avoid using the `Toast` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a Thread that every 30 seconds get the New message. If you don't want to use Toast, you can put a TextView into your activity and refresh its text property. For passing the message to the activity you can use a MessageHandler.

BestRegards.

Comment: Thanks that is great info, and I think that will help point me in the right direction. Just one quick follow up though... Will having a thread that executes every 30 seconds like that slow down the overall application significantly? Cheers!

Comment: Hi, excuse me for the long time to answer. Actually I am working in a project that sends location coordinate every 5 minutes, I am using a thread to send this coordinates, and this does not make the application slower. The only trouble I've found is that sometimes the OS restarts activities when needs to assign more memory to another process, but if your application is going to be opened the whole time, this is not a problem. BestRegards!

Comment: Ok that is great, and what I was kind of hoping would be the case. I have the thread up and going and it seems to be going great. Thanks again for the guidance, I really do appreciate it. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is probably using an AsyncTask (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).